# Is this Sitemap code correct?

Tags: sitemap, xml-sitemap

I'd like to check whether I have any of the code not as it should be in my Sitemap file.

Not sure if this is too general a question for here...

If it's an ok question, here's the sitemap URL: `http://wordfruit.com/sitemap.xml`

Comment: Yeah, code reviews are not on-topic here. The [code review site](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) is probably more appropriate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your sitemap is valid as you can check here:

- http://www.validome.org/google/
- http://sitemapxml.net/sitemap-validator.php